# logic in JSON Schemas

Tags: json, jsonschema

Is there an already established way of incorporating logic into a JSON Schema?

For example if I had a JSON of the following:

```
{
"Gross Pay": "100",
"Hours": "5",
"Rate": "20"
}
```

And I have a Schema requiring these 3 fields. If I wanted to ensure that the "Gross Pay" equals "Hours" x "Rate" where would be the best place to incorporate such logic?

Comment: You can use Javascript to check the condition. Use JSON.parse({"Gross Pay": "100", "Hours": "5", "Rate": "20"}) to convert into Javascript object and then do whatever you want.

Comment: more looking for a place to save the logic of "whatever you want"

Comment: There are all manner of tools for imposing schema on javascript.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't describe this type of assertions with JSON Schema. See [validation keywords](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html), there's nothing suitable there. There are some keywords like `minimum` or `exclusiveMaximum`, but they won't allow you to express `Gross Pay = Hours * Rate`.

Comment: Does it allow for custom fields where I can describe a unit test or something?

Comment: @Darcys22 You can add custom keywords as long as they don't conflict with standard ones. But don't just embed code to `eval()` - I'd never execute that.